# Find value in Table with several criterias

Tags: excel, vba

I have one sheet in workbook called "Assemble_Type". I have table on this sheet also called "Assemble_Type". The table has 3 columns and looks like this (see pic)

```
Sub testtables()
Dim Assemble_Type, Workshop, Packing As String
Dim Table_Assemble_Type As ListObject

Assemble_Type = "Assemble_Type"
Workshop = "Workshop"
Packing = "Packing"

Set Table_Assemble_Type = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Assemble_Type).ListObjects(Assemble_Type)


'some pseudocode I try to complete
if 
  Table_Assemble_Type.Column(Assemble_Type) = "main" _ And 
  Table_Assemble_Type.Column(Workshop) = "2" 
Then
  My_var = Table_Assemble_Type.Column(Packing) ' It stores cell value = 20
  My_row = Table_Assemble_Type.Column(Packing).RowInTable' it stores row of table = 4
'
```

I have reference to this table with "Table_Assemble_Type" variable, but I can't figure out how to find value 20 (in column "Packing") and number of row using table-object commands.

[pic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kYlR.png)

Comment: unclear what you need.......do you want the row numbers of the *20* s or the addresses of the *20* s ??

Comment: hello, sorry I missed some data. I edited the post please read it again:)